# Why can't I extend this partition into the unallocated space?

Tags: windows-7, disk-management

Check out the screenshot below, I want to extend my C partition (where Windows is installed) into the unallocated free space shown. This space was cleared up by shrinking the D partition. I can extend the D partition if I want to, but not the C.

Why not?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you can only extend a partition if the blank space is directly following it.  Your D: partition is in the way.

Perhaps look into a partitioning program like [GPartEd](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Ah, is there no way to move the unallocated block to in-between the two partitions using disk management?

Comment: Simplest way would be to create a 40GB partition transfer the data, delete the existing partition extend it the first partition, then reset the drive letter.  A tool that avoid doing that was alos suggested.

Comment: `Simplest way would be to create a 40GB partition transfer the data, delete the existing partition extend it the first partition, then reset the drive letter.`   @Ramhound, that’s not as simple as you think; you’ve overlooked the fact that the `D` volume is 67.42GB and the available space is only 40GB. @JMK, you’ll want to use a third-party partition-management program which can “shift” the `D` volume down for you (depending on how full it is, it might do a *whole lot* of thrashing as it moves all the data).